# Uploaded Image not loaded

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I upload an image to the server, it gets saved in the IIS website folder correctly. The problem is when returning from the Controller it still shows the previous image instead of the new one even though the image I see in the folder had been replaced. I thought it might be because of the cache and tried to:

```
namespace Web.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [System.Web.Mvc.OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public class EditProfileController : Controller
    ...
}
```

The photo upload works like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ActionResult UploadImage(MyModel profile)
  {
     // check if image exists, delete it and save new one
     ...
     RedirectToAction("EditView")
  }

  public ActionResult EditView()
  {
     ViewBag.Image  = getProfileImage();

     return View(myModel);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct, the uploaded image was still in cached with your browser. One of your solution was to implement versioning or in my part, GUID numbering system of filename to make sure the browser will get the latest file.

This is an example:

```
<img alt="Image" src="@href("~/Uploads/" + strImageFileName + Version )"
```

In your code behind file, you can do this:

```
var strImageFileName= string.Format(@"{0}.txt", Guid.NewGuid());
```

Although you add a NoCache attribute, still the browser will get the older file, and will be updated maybe 30 minutes or more, so you really need to have a different filename to make sure you loaded a fresh image.